# Telegram Bot to track Expenses - How to create buttons and Submenu buttons

Tags: python, google-sheets, python-telegram-bot

I am using Python Telegram Bot

I want to create a bot to track my expenses, the bot will read categories from my Google Sheet and will track user's responses in another google sheet. The categories have 3 levels: level1(Income, Expense); level2 (Salary, Bonuses, etc) and level3 (A,B,C).
I want the bot to show me the categories as buttons, si user click on level1: Income, then the bot shows me all subcategories in level2 under Income, then click on a subcategory and the bot shows me all level3 categories under level2.
The Bot will log all answers and then ask amount and short description (string).

I developed the code but I'm stuck trying the bot to show me level2 categories after user clicks on level1 (either Income or Expense buttons). I know that the cod knows if I click on Income or Expense, but I've been unable to make the bot to show me the next set of buttons based on the level1 button I clicked.

I've tried many options but not sure where to go now, also tried a couple of suggestions from ChatGPT unsucssesfully

This is the code:

```
import asyncio
import logging
import telegram
from telegram.constants import ParseMode
from telegram.ext import Application, MessageHandler, filters, CallbackQueryHandler, CommandHandler
from telegram import InlineKeyboardButton, InlineKeyboardMarkup

import gspread
from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()

# Telegram bot token
TELEGRAM_BOT_TOKEN = 'myToken'
bot = telegram.Bot(token=TELEGRAM_BOT_TOKEN)

# Google Sheets credentials
GOOGLE_SHEET_ID = 'MyGoogleSheetID'
SHEET_NAMEIn = 'MySheetAnswers'
SHEET_NAME = 'MyCategoryList'
SCOPE = ['https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds', 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive']
CREDS_JSON = 'MyPathToJsonFile'  

# Authenticate with Google Sheets
creds = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name(CREDS_JSON, SCOPE)
client = gspread.authorize(creds)
sheetIn = client.open_by_key(GOOGLE_SHEET_ID).worksheet(SHEET_NAMEIn)
sheet = client.open_by_key(GOOGLE_SHEET_ID).worksheet(SHEET_NAME)

# Fetch categories from the Google Sheet
categories_data = sheet.get_all_records()

# Define categories globally
categories = []
for category in categories_data:
    level1 = category.get("level1", "")
    level2 = category.get("level2", "")
    level3 = category.get("level3", "")

    # Find or create level 1
    parent_level1 = next((c for c in categories if c["name"] == level1), None)
    if not parent_level1:
        parent_level1 = {"id": str(len(categories) + 1), "name": level1, "subcategories": []}
        categories.append(parent_level1)

    # Find or create level 2 under level 1
    parent_level2 = next((c for c in parent_level1["subcategories"] if c["name"] == level2), None)
    if not parent_level2:
        parent_level2 = {"id": str(len(categories) + 1), "name": level2, "subcategories": []}
        parent_level1["subcategories"].append(parent_level2)

    # Create level 3 under level 2
    level3_category = {"id": str(len(categories) + 1), "name": level3, "subcategories": []}
    parent_level2["subcategories"].append(level3_category)

# Dictionary to store user responses
user_responses = {}

# Function to start the conversation
async def start(update, context):
    await update.message.reply_text("Welcome! Let's get started.")
    await ask_category(update, context, categories)

# Function to ask for category
async def ask_category(update, context, categories):
    # Access the global categories variable
    # global categories

    # Create keyboard with categories
    keyboard = [[InlineKeyboardButton(category["name"], callback_data=f'category_{category["id"]}') for category in categories]]
    reply_markup = InlineKeyboardMarkup(keyboard)

    # Check if the update object and its message attribute are not None
    if update and update.message:
        await update.message.reply_text("Please select a category:", reply_markup=reply_markup)
    else:
        print("Update or message is None. Could not send the reply1.")
        # You can log the error, send a default message, or take other actions as needed

# Function to ask for subcategory
async def ask_subcategory(update, context, category_id):
    # Access the global categories variable
    global categories
    
    category = next((c for c in categories if c["id"] == category_id), None)
    if category:
        # Create keyboard with subcategories
        subcategory_buttons = [
            InlineKeyboardButton(subcategory["name"], callback_data=f'subcategory_{category_id}_{i+1}') 
            for i, subcategory in enumerate(category["subcategories"])
        ]
        reply_markup = InlineKeyboardMarkup([subcategory_buttons])

        # Check if the update object and its message attribute are not None
        if update and update.message:
            await update.message.reply_text(f"Please select a subcategory for {category['name']}:", reply_markup=reply_markup)
        else:
            print("Update or message is None. Could not send the reply2.")
            # You can log the error, send a default message, or take other actions as needed

# Function to ask for level3 subcategory
async def ask_level3_subcategory(update, context, category_id, subcategory_index):
    # Access the global categories variable
    global categories
    
    category = next((c for c in categories if c["id"] == category_id), None)
    if category and subcategory_index <= len(category["subcategories"]):
        selected_subcategory = category["subcategories"][subcategory_index - 1]
        # Create keyboard with level3 subcategories
        level3_buttons = [
            InlineKeyboardButton(level3_subcategory["name"], callback_data=f'level3_subcategory_{category_id}_{subcategory_index}_{i+1}') 
            for i, level3_subcategory in enumerate(selected_subcategory.get("subcategories", []))
        ]
        reply_markup = InlineKeyboardMarkup([level3_buttons])
        await update.message.reply_text(f"Please select a level3 subcategory for {selected_subcategory['name']}:", reply_markup=reply_markup)

# Function to ask for amount and description
async def ask_amount_and_description(update):
    await update.message.reply_text("Great! Now, please provide the amount and description.")

# New navigate_categories function
async def navigate_categories(update, context, category_id, level):
    global categories

    # Find the selected category object
    selected_category = next((c for c in categories if c["id"] == category_id and c["name"]), None)
    if selected_category:
        # Check if the update object and its message attribute are not None
        if update and update.message:
            print("Debug: Sending reply.")
            # Branch based on level
            if level == 1:
                # Get and display level 2 categories
                subcategory_buttons = [
                    InlineKeyboardButton(subcategory["name"], callback_data=f'subcategory_{category_id}_{i+1}') 
                    for i, subcategory in enumerate(selected_category["subcategories"])
                ]
                reply_markup = InlineKeyboardMarkup([subcategory_buttons])
                await update.message.reply_text(f"Please select a subcategory for {selected_category['name']}:", reply_markup=reply_markup)
                # Update user data and call the function again for level 2
                context.user_data["current_category"] = selected_category
                await navigate_categories(update, context, subcategory_buttons[0].callback_data.split("_")[1], 2)

            elif level == 2:
                # Get and display level 3 categories
                level3_buttons = [
                    InlineKeyboardButton(level3_subcategory["name"], callback_data=f'level3_subcategory_{category_id}_{i+1}') 
                    for i, level3_subcategory in enumerate(selected_category["subcategories"])
                ]
                reply_markup = InlineKeyboardMarkup([level3_buttons])
                await update.message.reply_text(f"Please select a third-level subcategory for {selected_category['name']}:", reply_markup=reply_markup)
                # Update user data and call the function again for level 3
                context.user_data["current_category"] = selected_category
                await navigate_categories(update, context, level3_buttons[0].callback_data.split("_")[1], 3)

            elif level == 3:
                # Get and display level 4 categories (if any)
                level4_buttons = [
                    InlineKeyboardButton(level4_subcategory["name"], callback_data=f'level4_subcategory_{category_id}_{i+1}') 
                    for i, level4_subcategory in enumerate(selected_category["subcategories"])
                ]
                reply_markup = InlineKeyboardMarkup([level4_buttons])
                await update.message.reply_text(f"Please select a fourth-level subcategory for {selected_category['name']}:", reply_markup=reply_markup)
                # Update user data and call the function again for level 4
                context.user_data["current_category"] = selected_category
                await navigate_categories(update, context, level4_buttons[0].callback_data.split("_")[1], 4)
        else:
            print("Debug: Update or message is None. Could not send the reply.")
            # You can log the error, send a default message, or take other actions as needed
    else:
        print("Debug: Selected category is None or has an empty name. Could not send the reply.")
        # You can log the error, send a default message, or take other actions as needed

# Function to handle button clicks
async def button_click(update, context):
    query = update.callback_query
    user_id = query.from_user.id

    # Parse the callback data
    data_parts = query.data.split('_')
    selection_type, *selection_values = data_parts

    # Log user selection
    if selection_type == 'category':
        category_id = selection_values[0]
        user_responses['category'] = category_id
        print(f"Debug: Selected category ID: {category_id}")
        print(f"Debug: Categories: {categories}")
        await navigate_categories(update, context, category_id, 1)
    elif selection_type == 'subcategory':
        subcategory_index = int(selection_values[1])
        user_responses['subcategory'] = selection_values[0]
        print(f"Debug: Selected subcategory ID: {user_responses['subcategory']}")
        await navigate_categories(update, context, user_responses['subcategory'], 2)
    elif selection_type == 'level3_subcategory':
        user_responses['level3_subcategory'] = selection_values[0]
        print(f"Debug: Selected level3_subcategory ID: {user_responses['level3_subcategory']}")
        await ask_amount_and_description(update)

    # Answer callback query
    await query.answer()

# Function to handle text input
async def handle_text_input(update, context):
    # Log user text input
    user_responses['text_input'] = update.message.text

    # Log all user responses to Google Sheets
    sheetIn.append_row(list(context.user_data.values()))

    # End the conversation
    await update.message.reply_text("Thank you! Conversation completed.")

# Set up handlers
start_handler = CommandHandler('start', start)
button_handler = CallbackQueryHandler(button_click)
def text_input_handler(update, context):
    if update.message.text and not update.message.is_command():
        handle_text_input(update, context)

text_input_handler = MessageHandler(filters.Text and ~filters.COMMAND, text_input_handler)

# Create and run the application
application = Application.builder().token(TELEGRAM_BOT_TOKEN).build()
application.add_handler(start_handler)
application.add_handler(button_handler)
application.add_handler(text_input_handler)
application.run_polling()
```

This is my category list structure:

| id | level1 | level2 | level3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Income |  |  |
| 101 |  | Sueldo |  |
| 1011 |  |  | Salario |
| 1012 |  |  | Propinas |
| 1013 |  |  | Bonos |
| 1014 |  |  | Comisiones |
| 1015 |  |  | Otros |
| 102 |  | Otro Ingreso |  |
| 1021 |  |  | Transferencia de ahorros |
| 1022 |  |  | Ingreso por intereses |
| 1023 |  |  | Dividendos |
| 1024 |  |  | Regalos |
| 1025 |  |  | Reembolsos |
| 1026 |  |  | Otros |
| 2 | Expense |  |  |
| 201 |  | Diarios |  |
| 2011 |  |  | Comida |
| 2012 |  |  | Restaurantes |
| 2013 |  |  | Higiene personal |
| 2014 |  |  | Ropa |
| 2015 |  |  | Productos de limpieza |
| 2016 |  |  | Meriendas |
| 2017 |  |  | Otros |
| 202 |  | Vivienda |  |
| 2021 |  |  | Renta |
| 2022 |  |  | GC |
| 2023 |  |  | Amoblado |
| 2024 |  |  | Decoración |
| 2025 |  |  | Mantenimiento |
| 2026 |  |  | Mudanza |
| 2027 |  |  | Otros |
| 203 |  | Servicios |  |
| 2031 |  |  | Celulares |
| 2032 |  |  | Internet |
| 2033 |  |  | Electricidad |
| 2034 |  |  | Agua |
| 2035 |  |  | Gas |
| 2036 |  |  | Otros |
| ... | ... | ... | ... |

Answer (score 0):

IISC you want the bot to track which "state" a current conversation is in, i.e. you need a stateful handling of the updates with something like an [FSM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite-state_machine). PTB provides the [`ConversationHandler`](https://docs.python-telegram-bot.org/en/stable/telegram.ext.conversationhandler.html) for such use cases and there is [this example](https://docs.python-telegram-bot.org/en/stable/examples.html#examples-inlinekeyboard2) specifically about inline buttons.

---

Disclaimer: I'm currently the maintainer of `python-telegram-bot`.